# Camel "Composed Message Processor" how to detect "onComplete"

Tags: apache-camel

In my camel route i have to use [Composed Message Processor](http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html). That means i first have to split the exchange (on big result set from db) and then i have to aggregate it.

The problem i see by using the decoupled seda queue is how to detect that the work is done (the route is triggered manually, and will run for some hours ). I have to call back to the infrastructure that the work is done.

Using "splitter only" variant is no good option because i would loose the aggreagator-correlation-logic (correlated exchanges must be in order). But the biggest problem is loosing the completionSize. I can't aggregate into multiple groups.

Here is an example for the pattern:

```
from("direct:start")
    .split().body()
    .end()
    .to("seda:aggregate");

// collect and re-assemble the validated OrderItems into an order again
from("seda:aggregate")
    .process(setHeaders)
    .aggregate(new MyOrderAggregationStrategy()).header("orderId").completionSize(header("count"))
    .parallelProcessing()
    .process(doTheWork)
    .to("mock:result");
```

Here an example for splitter only:

```
from("direct:start")
    .routePolicy( finishNotifier ) //implements onExchangeDone
    .split(body(), new MyOrderStrategy())
    .parallelProcessing()
    .process(doTheWork)
    .to("bean:MyOrderService?method=buildCombinedResponse")
```

As a side note: just chaining split and aggregate only works if parallelProcessing is disabled. With enabled parallelProcessing "doTheWork" is called after finishNotifier.onExchangeDone. Since i call context.stop() if work finishes, "process" method were called after camel stopped!

Comment: Can you please post a simplified version of your route, and what you mean by "splitter only" variant.

Comment: added examples for both variants

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own custom aggregation strategy that relies on a counting the number of received exchanges vs. the total number of records your process has.  You can also check out the camel in action book chapters 8-10 for very good reference examples of the splitter and aggregation patterns for a lot of base implementation examples.  I strongly recommend at least picking up a PDF copy if you are using camel because it can get your typical enterprise use cases covered fairly easily.

This blog post is also fantastic for working out some of the issues with getting your aggregation setup correctly for your use case:

http://tmielke.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-camel-aggregator-correctly.html

Comment: thanks, but i know the book and i know the blog. the last days i read much about my problem. I also filed a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9222
In my special case i don't know the number of all entries to be processed upfront.

Comment: Then I would recommend adding a control message when you finish processing all of the files.  You could add a method after the split that sends the final count number count as a header to the route with the aggregator which can interpret that message separately and update your aggregation instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question but i found a very simple solution. The reason i came across this pattern was a suggestion in camel users group. The underlying problem was the [broken(imho) parallelProcessing()](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9222) in aggregator pattern.
My original route just chains splitter and aggregator but in need multi threading on the output of aggregator.

The solution was simple: just use "[threads()](http://camel.apache.org/async.html)" instead of parallelProcessing().